# AngularJS Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get some data to app.js from the config.js file. But I have some problems.It give me an uncaught reference error.

config.js

```
var configData={
'cfg':{

    'MyData':'Datatasdasdasd',

}};
```

app.js

```
 var app=angular.module('myapp', ['appConfig'])
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope,cfg) {
    $scope.yazdir=cfg.MyData;

    });

var config_module = angular.module('appConfig', []);
angular.forEach(configData, function(key, value) {
    config_module.constant(value, key);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">
<div>
    {yazdir}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: i.e probably because you are loading config.js after app.js

Comment: I have uncaught reference error. configData is not defined.

Comment: when i change scripts order problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts are in the wrong order:

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```